# How fast do I have to dry myself for a hot shower to heat my body?

Tags: thermodynamics, approximations

I am not a physicist. I would like to know how fast do I have to dry myself after taking a hot shower to get more heat from the shower, than lost because the water on my skin increasing heat exchange rate.

Lets assume I took a shower for 30 minutes in 40°C water.
The room I will dry myself in is 22°C.
Also lets assume that I am a healthy human with 36°C temperature.

For the sake of simplicity lets assume that I will wait before drying myself and the drying happens instantly, also the water won't evaporate and the air will have a constant temperature around me.

We could simplify the heating process also by assuming the water is of constant temperature and touching only 1/3 of the body on average.

The cooling where the water doesn't touch the skin could be ignored for further simplicity.

I also found the heat conductance of skin is on average: 0,37(W/m/°C)

Lets assume a human with a surface of 1,75 square meters.

Comment: i am afraid that this is pretty complex heat-transfer problem. However, it might be rephrased in something like problem of joined water evaporation, diffusion (into towel), heat transfer and from water (into air and body) on single plane, essentially making it one-dimensional problem

Comment: Doing the experiment may get you better results than doing a calculation.

Comment: @mmesser314 It is hard because the human heat "feel" is relative. And if you want to measure temperature, the skin might not be the same as the inner, also there is the problem of the body (over)compensating for cold.

Comment: @aandreev I was thinking along the lines of some approximation. The only information that seems to be missing is the heat conductance of wet vs dry skin to air.

Comment: wet skin is just dry skin layer with water...

Comment: @aandreev I lack the knowledge to do the calculations myself.(Your last comment proves that) But I tried to simplify the question.